# Multiple Class Path Specification - Could not create the Java virtual machine

Tags: java, classpath

I am creating a Submission System where I would like my Java Framework .class files kept at a specific location and another .class file uploaded by a user in another location. The Framework should find the uploaded .class file at runtime and input various test data.

The command I'm using to set the multiple class paths is as follows;

> java -cp 
>   /users/userD/SubmissionSystem/Java/Assessment4/Framework:/users/userD/SubmissionSystem/Java/Assessment4/Test
>   2>&1 
>   -dataset=/home/users/userD/SubmissionSystem/Java/Assessment4/Test/dataset_9.dat

Though, I'm recieving the following error in the terminal;

> Unrecognized option:
>   -dataset=/home/users/userD/SubmissionSystem/Java/Assessment4/Test/dataset_9.dat
>
> Could not create the Java virtual machine.

I'm trying to set the class paths to look for the .class files not .jar files, but with no luck!

Any help would be very appreciated! Thanks.

---

Removing the following from the command (this was concatenated afterwards)

> -dataset=/home/users/userD/SubmissionSystem/Java/Assessment4/Test/dataset_9.dat

I'm left with:

> java -cp /users/userD/SubmissionSystem/Java/Assessment4/Framework:/users/userD/SubmissionSystem/Java/Assessment4/Test

Though the java -help list appears, I think I'm missing an argument from the command?

---

According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/classpath.html

The correct syntax to set the class path in regards to my problem was:

> java -cp
>   /users/userD/SubmissionSystem/Java/Assessment4/Framework:/users/userD/SubmissionSystem/Java/Assessment4/Test filename

with the addition of the filename with no extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to specify the class you want to run as main, like "java -cp classpath classname arguments". It has to be the full name, too, e.g. "com.stackoverflow.SomeClass".

The classpath tells the JVM where to find the code, but may contain more than one executable class, which is why you have to name it in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I was missing the file extension from the end. The class path javadoc confused me a little!

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/java.html), there is no option called `dataset`.

<sup><sub>PS: Although the link says Solaris, it applies to Linux as well.</sub></sup>.